# Combining 100 json files from BigQuery that have the same structure

Tags: java, python, json, r, google-bigquery

I had to export a table(3.8GB) from BigQuery into GCP, which separated my table into 100 smaller json files, 100mb each.
Now I want to be able to put them back into one json file. Is there any efficient way to do that? It could be in R, Python, Java.
Or if anybody knows a better way to deal with these files, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose several files in GCS into a new huge file with one command:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose

> Note that there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation.
>
> There is a limit (currently 1024) to the total number of components for a given composite object. This means you can append to each object at most 1023 times.
>
> There is a per-project rate limit (currently 200) to the number of components you can compose per second. This rate counts both the components being appended to a composite object as well as the components being copied when the composite object of which they are a part is copied.

Comment: Thank you Felipe, this works better when you want to combine only several files but not quite for me, cuz I have to type in each of the files.. (if I understood it correctly.)  btw, I watched some of your youtube videos, good to see you here!

Comment: Try with a * glob?

Comment: yes that works! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Cloud Dataflow. Might be a little bit of overkill, but it works well. I already wrote a pipeline that you can use so you don't need to code it up yourself: https://github.com/shinesolutions/bigquery-table-to-one-file

Comment: This looks great, but unfortunately I don't have access to Cloud Dataflow....

Comment: Why not? If you're got access to BQ then Dataflow should be a breeze. It's just part of the Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

In Java,
For this, I will write a script which will first convert one file into Object of your json data. And in any loop, I will do same for your 100 files and set those objects into list. So that I can write that list in single file easily using Jackson library.

To convert your Json file data to Pojo, you can take help of a site mentioned below :
http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/